# Q range calculation

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

I did a neutron diffraction experiment and I need to figure out which Q range we used. How  should I calculate it from the incident wavelength and the diffraction angle?

Comment: Was the scattering elastic or inelastic? This will make a difference. By diffraction I assume you mean elastic, but of course one should not assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantity $Q$ is the scattering vector. It's the difference between in wavevector of the incoming neutrons and the scattered neutrons. A quick Google found this diagram that explains how to calculate $Q$:

[image: Scattering vector]